# Move drop shadow of TabWidget along with it to bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabwidget, dropshadow

I have an app that uses fragments and tabs. I have moved the tabs to the bottom of screen, but the tabwidget's shadow still at the top of the screen(. How to show it above the tabwidget.
My main xml is same as in the following question, but slightly modified as suggested in its answer..

[How to show the Tab bar in bottom, -Tab with Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524125/how-to-show-the-tab-bar-in-bottom-tab-with-fragment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using

```
android:foreground="@drawable/drop_shadow"
android:foregroundGravity="bottom|fill_horizontal"
```

on the `FrameLayout` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup this style to fragments or activities in the tabs:

```
    <style
        name="NoWindowContentOverlay">
    <item
        name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I have already done this to hide the shadow for now.. But i need to show the shadow at the right place..

Comment: I'm not sure if there is API for it, but you can do it manually by using special tab widget background with negative margin